# Eureka client exception com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I am new to microservices. I'm trying to create one small application for learning purpose. Here is my code:
EurekaServer - application.yml

```
    spring:
     application:
      name: EurekaServer

    server:
     port: 8080
     servlet:
      context-path: /EurekaServer

    eureka:
     client:
      fetch-registry: false
      register-with-eureka: false
```

Eureka Server is working fine and I am able to see the dashboard at [http://localhost:8080/EurekaServer](http://localhost:8080/EurekaServer/)

EmployeeClient: application.yml is below:

```
    spring:
     application:
      name: EmployeeClient

    server:
     port: 8586

    eureka:
     client: 
      serviceUrl:
       defaultZone: http://localhost:8080/EurekaServer
```

In last line I need to write serviceUrl explicitly as on pressing ctrl+space in sts it doesnot show option serviceUrl but it shows service-url, hyphen sign. And same with defaultZone. Am I missing some jar or specific version?

My EmployeeClientApplication.java

```
    @EnableEurekaClient
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class EmployeeClientApplication {

       public static void main(String[] args) {
          SpringApplication.run(EmployeeClientApplication.class, args);
       }
    }
```

when I try to run EmployeeClientApplication.java it gives me below exception:

```
    com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server
```

I also tried using @EnableDiscoveryClient in place of @EnableEurekaClient, but with no luck.

A part of EmployeeClient pom.xml is below:

```
    <parent>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
       <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
       <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
      <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
      <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
      <java.version>1.8</java.version>
      <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

   <dependencies>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
    <dependency>
```

Where I'm making a mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use below line in EmployeeClient application.yml

```
    defaultZone: http://localhost:8080/EurekaServer/eureka
```

Answer (score 7):

I think, you will have to change default Zone in client property from **/EurekaServer** to **/eureka**

```
eureka:
     client: 
      serviceUrl:
       defaultZone: http://localhost:8080/eureka
```

**"/eureka" is the rest endpoint to register services to eureka registry.** 
Make the changes and try, it should work.

In addition to this, if you are willing to change the UI dashboard url you should use eureka.dashboard.path property.

Comment: yes, your answer was half correct, it gave me an idea. I answered below. +1 for your answer. thanks buddy.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `eureka.instance.hostname=localhost` can solve your issue, if you have added DiscoveryServer as the application name in the server's application properties file.

Comment: You can check my answer below.

Comment: I had already added that property, yet was getting the error given above!